# bypass dispose for testing

Tags: c#, tdd, typemock

I'm trying to test a method. 
I want to ensrur that there is a method call in that method (calling service) 
the code look like this:

```
using(proxy = new Proxy())
{ 
      proxy.CallService();
}
```

I swap the proxy with fake object (using TypeMock) 
but get error because of the fake object disposed in the end of block. 
I don't want to remove that "using" block. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work at Typemock
If you are using the Arrange Act Assert API you can use Members.ReturnRecursiveFakes
when you are creating your fake object (Note: this is the default from version 5.2.0)
This will automatically fake the Dispose method as well.

so your test will be something like this:

```
var fake = Isolate.Fake.Instance<Proxy>(Members.ReturnRecursiveFakes);
Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fake.CallService()).IgnoreCall();
Isolate.Swap.NextInstance<Proxy>().With(fake);

UnderTest classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();
classUnderTest.MethodUnderTest(); // assuming the Proxy instance is used here.

Isolate.Verify.WasCalledWithAnyArguments(()=>fake.CallService());
```

I want to add to what Jon Skeet said that I would create a separate test that will ensure that the Dispose method is called.
I think it is a good practice to assert one thing in each test method, that way when a test breaks up you'll know the reason immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Make the mock object expect to be disposed too. (I don't know TypeMock, but in some other mocking frameworks this would just be a case of calling `Dispose` yourself during the "record" phase.) In fact, I'd say that without that the test is wrong anyway, because presumably you want to be certain that the proxy *is* being disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Just instruct your mock of Proxy to expect a call to `Dispose()` as well. If you're using reflective mocks you need to do something like this

```
var proxyMock = MockManager.Mock(typeof(Proxy));
// set up regular calls to proxy, e.g.
proxyMock.ExpectCall("CallService");
proxyMock.ExpectCall("Dispose");
```

for natural mocks place a call to `Dispose()` in your using block.

Answer (score 0):

Make the fake object implement IDisposable:

```
class FakeObject : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose() {}
}
```

Comment: OP is using TypeMock, so there is no explicit fake proxy class.